# Unexpected token ) на chrome 49, а на 72 все ок

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Использую Хром на ХР 49 версии и при загрузке страницы выпадает alert(Unexpected token ) ). На версии 72 все отлично работает. 
Нашел код из-за чего это происходит

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<?php echo $root?>/views/js/createGrids.js?2017_09_08"></script>
```

А сама функция вызывается ниже в теге скрипт

```
function onLoadPage(){
 createGrids();
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  for(let grd in oGrids){   
    if(oGrids[grd]!=null && oGrids[grd].extOptions && oGrids[grd].extOptions.pivotTable==true){
         getPivotData(oGrids[grd]);
     }  
   }
  }, 50) }
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: И фун-ция onLoadPage и вызывает ошибку
А вызывается она
< .body id="document_body" onload="onLoadPage()">

Comment: Ну, очевидно в createGrids.js используется что-то из JavaScript, чего 49 хром еще не понимал. Но так как содержимое этого файла остается тайной, большего сказать нельзя. :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `let` на `var` заменить.

Comment: Был var сделал let и результат тот же (

Comment: @DedZamay тогда ошибка не в `onLoadPage`. Запускайте отладчик и смотрите трассировку.